# Get vector from array .csv file

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays, csv, vector

I hope you can help me. I want to create a variable with name 'x' with the values of the column with header 'x' of the array .csv file called 'data' (please see below). Could you help me do it?

.csv array semicolon separed:

```
data ='x';'y';'z'\\
      1;2;3\\
      4;5;6\\
      7;8;9
```

I would like to obtain: x = column vector [1;4;7]

I want to do this in a TikZ environment.

Another question: If I were to evaluate the value of the 3rd element of 'x', how could I do it?

I would like to get the value x(3) = 7.

Also, I would like to obtain the minimum value of the column 1 of the vector 'x', how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I use `readarray` to import the data and `listofitems` to parse it.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.csv}
data ='x';'ycol';'z'\\
      1;2;3\\
      4;5;6\\
      7;8;9
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,listofitems}
\newcommand\arrayelement[2]{%
  \def\tmpA{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\dataarray[1]{%
    \edef\tmpB{\dataarray[1,\zcnt,2]}%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\tmpA}{\tmpB} = 0 \dataarray[#2+1,\zcnt]\fi
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\readdef{data.csv}\mydata
\setsepchar{\\/;/'}
\readlist*\dataarray{\mydata}

\arrayelement{x}{2},
\arrayelement{ycol}{1},
\arrayelement{z}{3}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!